# Ignore comment tags OR change text to backslashes with JS

Tags: javascript, html, comments

I'm trying to replace HTML like so

```
document.getElementById('someelement').innerHTML = "////////<br>\\\\\\\";
```

But it appears it is not registering the backslashes because it thinks they are comment tags(?) Is there any way I can prevent javascript from reading these as comment tags?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a *single* backslash (`\`) into a string, it has to be doubled. The list of backslashes at the end of your string has an odd number of them, so you need to add one more. The error you'd get in the console would be "Unterminated string literal", because the effect of that error is that the closing double-quote mark appears to be itself quoted by the backslash, as it would be if you intended to include a double-quote as part of the string.

Also it's `.getElementById()`, not `getElementId()`.